# Error in writing a dictionary to a file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a dictionary `invIndex` to a text file. I found the following post:

and I wrote these lines:

```
import csv
f = open('result.csv','wb')
w = csv.DictWriter(f,invIndex)
w.writerow(invIndex)
f.close()
```

When I reach this line: `w.writerow(invIndex)`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

How can I write a dictionary to a text file correctly.

Comment: I understood that you have a dictionary. I wanted to know what was *in* the dictionary. As it turns out that is a moot point though.

Comment: You need to be clearer in what you expect to find in your file after writing. Including example input and output would help.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, csv writers and readers expect a text stream, but `open(.., 'wb')` (or more precisely, the `b` creates a byte stream). Try:

```
import csv
invIndex = [
  {'fruit': 'apple',  'count': '10'},
  {'fruit': 'banana', 'count': '42'}]
with open('result.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, invIndex[0].keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(invIndex)
```

Replace `utf-8` with the [encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) you want to use. It will write a file like

```
fruit,count
apple,10
banana,42
```

Comment: This only writes the dictionary values while I need the keys as well.

Comment: @user2192774 Well, that's another, unrelated problem. Updated with a solution. The question doesn't explain out what precisely is in `invIndex`, so I've added an example value.

Comment: The dictionary I have is something like: `{'first':{0,1,2}, 'second':{2,3}, etc .. }`. When I tried your script in my data, I got an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: 0`

Comment: @user2192774 Well, `{0,1,2}` is a set, which is unordered. Are you sure that your the values are not lists? In any cast, what output do you expect?

Comment: Yes I am sure they are sets. I just want to write the dictionary to a text file or csv. The whole purpose is that the dictionary is long so I can not view all values in the cmd. Therefore, I decided to write it to a file.

Comment: @user2192774 Well, what output do you expect then? It looks like CSV is not the right tool here. Why don't you just pipe the output into [`less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less)?, or use [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) instead of csv?

Comment: Csv is not a good choice for that sort of data, you could bend things to make it work, but you'll be messing about all over the place and you've have to do that in every application that needed to produce or consumee the data.

Comment: @phihag: print will do the purpose, but because the dictionary items are a lot, the cmd screen does not scroll for the beginning of the dictionary. The output only show me the last portion. For this reason, I decided to write the dictionary items to a file so I can search on certain values I want. If you can help me on writing the dictionary to a text file, that does the purpose but even this is not working with me.

Comment: @user2192774 No offense, but you should really make your last comment into [a new question "How can I examine a large value?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=How+can+I+examine+a+large+value&tags=python3). As I wrote above, piping the output into [`less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less) allows you to scroll and search, and [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) allows you to output it nicely (to a file or stdout). In any case, [**please open a new question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - this question has nothing to do with your actual problem.