# How can I examine a large value

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in Python that looks as follows:

```
{'first':{0,1,2}, 'second':{2,3}, etc .. }
```

There are lots of items so I can not scroll over them in the cmd. Therefore, I tried some methods to write the output to a file but it did not work with me (see: [Error in writing a dictionary to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511606/error-in-writing-a-dictionary-to-a-file/17511746?noredirect=1#comment25460434_17511746)).

Now, I need a method that allows me to view the dictionary content and also search over the content (ctrl-F or similar). I am a new to python so kindly bear this in mind and try to answer me in step-by-step fashion

Comment: What do you want to search? keys or values? We don't do Ctrl-f on data-structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pprint.pprint()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) to print formatted representations that are *usually* not that wide. You'll have to use your terminal functionality to search though. Use Python itself to search through dictionaries:

```
print next((key, dictionary[key] for key in dictionary if 'some_search' in key), None)
```

would find a key-value pair where `some_search` is contained in the key value.

You may want to look into an alternative shell such as [iPython](http://ipython.org/), or an [alternative terminal for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724/better-windows-command-line-shells) that offers a little more functionality over the bare-bones CMD.